# Does the OnePlus 3 Oreo update remove the engineering tool backdoor?

Tags: rooting, oneplus-3

The OnePlus 3 and other other OnePlus models had a engineering tool left in it that could allow root access without having to unlock the bootloader and flash custom recovery. The [OnePlus response](https://www.xda-developers.com/oneplus-root-access-backdoor/) said that this tool would be removed in an upcoming update.

Now, Android Oreo is [rolling out](https://www.xda-developers.com/oneplus-root-access-backdoor/) to the OnePlus 3 and 3T. Does this update remove the tool?

Answer (score 1):

No, the latest Oreo update `1f602` for the 3 and 3T have not removed the EngineeringMode or the OnePlusLogKit. This is as of 11/20/2017 at 9:30 pm.